# How do I reiterate through multiple variables

Tags: r, loops

I have a sample dataset as below:

```
Day<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
Group<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
Rain<-c(4,4,6,5,3,4,5,5,3,6,6,6,5,3,3,3,2,5,2)
UV<-c(6,6,7,8,5,6,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,5,6,8,5,7)

dat<-data.frame(Day,Group,Rain,UV)
```

I want to run a Kruskal Wallis test among 'A','B' and 'C' in "Group" for the variables "Rain" and "UV".
At present, I am subsetting the variables one by one for Kruskal test as below:

```
dat_Rain<-dat%>%select(c(Day,Group,Rain))

library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)
dat_Rain%>% 
  group_by(Day) %>% 
  kruskal_test(Rain ~ Group)
```

How do I reiterate Kruskal test for multiple variables (Rain,UV) in this dataset? Thanks.

Comment: You could reshape to long format and use a second grouping variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the columns that you want to apply `kruskal_test` and use `map_df` to get all the values in one dataframe.

```
library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)

cols <- c('Rain', 'UV')
map_df(cols, ~dat %>% group_by(Day) %>% kruskal_test(reformulate('Group', .x)))

#    Day .y.       n statistic    df      p method        
#  <dbl> <chr> <int>     <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <chr>         
#1     1 Rain      9     0.505     2 0.777  Kruskal-Wallis
#2     2 Rain     10     6.52      2 0.0384 Kruskal-Wallis
#3     1 UV        9     1.16      2 0.56   Kruskal-Wallis
#4     2 UV       10     0.423     2 0.809  Kruskal-Wallis
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lapply` and making use of a helper function this could be achieved like so:

Additionally I made use of `bind_rows` to bind the resulting list into one data frame.

```r
Day<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
Group<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
Rain<-c(4,4,6,5,3,4,5,5,3,6,6,6,5,3,3,3,2,5,2)
UV<-c(6,6,7,8,5,6,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,5,6,8,5,7)

dat<-data.frame(Day,Group,Rain,UV)

library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)

kt <- function(x, data) {
  fmla <- as.formula(paste(x, "~ Group"))
  
  data %>% 
    group_by(Day) %>% 
    kruskal_test(fmla)
}

lapply(c("Rain", "UV"), kt, data = dat) %>% 
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>     Day .y.       n statistic    df      p method        
#>   <dbl> <chr> <int>     <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <chr>         
#> 1     1 Rain      9     0.505     2 0.777  Kruskal-Wallis
#> 2     2 Rain     10     6.52      2 0.0384 Kruskal-Wallis
#> 3     1 UV        9     1.16      2 0.56   Kruskal-Wallis
#> 4     2 UV       10     0.423     2 0.809  Kruskal-Wallis
```